# Is there a database of wars in Europe since 1945?

Tags: europe, war, warfare, cold-war, contemporary-history

I'm currently improving a Timeline I build some time ago, this [Timeline of Wars in Europe since 1945](https://www.historytimeline.com/list/wars-in-europe/). I did used several sources, including Wikidata, to get the list of conflicts to include. Yet, there are minor conflicts, terrorist attacks and more events that could be included. It's a pain to pick what to include. After all, what is a war and what is not a war?

I'm looking for a **database of conflicts in post-IIWW Europe**. Is there a dataset like this that could provide a list of wars in Europe?

[image: Wars in Europe Time since 2WW]

Comment: Can you define "war"? or "conflict"?

Comment: If you want to make a chart like yours, *you* have to decide what counts as a war.

Comment: ...and what counts as the beginning and the end of a war, especially when you're counting in civil wars and guerilla activities. I'd also hesitate to call the Cold War an actual conflict, because it distinguished itself in that there *wasn't* an actual war going on (hence "cold" war).

Comment: Definitions are problematic, not only for the including part, but for categorization. I use orange for rebellions, unrest, etc But then, some guerrilla warfare is just so intese that fits more with the red (like wars), so creating a "legend" of this with good categories is an issue, well, it takes work to figure out a good system.

Comment: You have inculded the Northern Ireland conflict, would you include the bloodshed due to the left-wing terrorist groups in Europe?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-wing_terrorism#Europe

Answer (score 5):

There are datasets, but using them requires attention to the definitions (which may not be the ones you prefer). Look at [this one](https://ucdp.uu.se/) from Uppsala University, which defines war as 1,000 battle deaths in one calendar year.

Comment: Good one. Definitions are an issue, so true. Using a dataset that someone has already curated and justified/researched is a good starting point.